# Limit concurrent execution of jobs in clustered Quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We have a system running on OpenShift (Kubernetes) where there are 4 pods (one instance of JVM with our application running in each pod). This application uses Quartz and is clustered using JDBC JobStore.

We basically use Quartz to process large files (up to 50 MB) asynchronously. So, when we receive a file, we would kick off a Quartz job to start processing the file immediately and acknowledge that we received the file to the sender.

If we received several files at the same time (say, 20) each application instance (pod with JVM) will start processing 5 files at the same time. That would require each application instance to have 250 MB of data in memory just for the raw data, plus additional memory for processing. What I want to do is, to limit each instance of application to process only one file at a time, which means, one Quartz job at a time. Since we have 4 application instances in the cluster, we will process 4 files at a time. I don't want Quartz to trigger 5 Jobs in each application instance. Instead, Quarts should trigger one job and then wait until that finishes in that application instance before triggering the next.

I was looking at @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation. I am not sure that I understand this completely. Does that

1. Prevent Quartz from executing parallel jobs in the entire cluster
   which means, even though we have 4 application instances, only one
   instance will process a job at one time and the other 3 will be idle
2. Prevent Quartz from executing parallel jobs in each application
   instance in the cluster, which means we will have 4 jobs running
   (one job in each application instance)

What I need is option 2. Does this @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation do that? If not, is there any other way I could achieve this?